# REST API - POST Attribute error

Tags: magento2, rest-api

My post of an attribute is not working anymore (it has worked, checked git history).

```
    {
        "attribute":{
        "attribute_code":"some_other_stuff",
            "is_html_allowed_on_front":true,
            "frontend_labels ":[  
             {
                 "store_id":1,
                "label":"Component type"
             },
             {
                 "store_id":2,
                "label":"Component type"
             }
          ],
          "frontend_input":"select",
          "is_visible_on_front":true,
          "scope":"global",
          "options":[]
       }
    }
```

it returns

```
    {
        "message": "Invalid value of \"%value\" provided for the %fieldName field.",
        "parameters": {
            "fieldName": "frontend_label",
            "value": null
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Which APi you tried? Can you post the full API code?